# Como fechar um td com um tr após o loop e continuar imprimindo o resto do código em PHP

Tags: php, mysql

tudo bem? estou com um pequeno problema ao pegar os dados de um banco de dados e tentar transformá-lo em um tipo de tabela, acontece que eu estou buscando os dados que preciso para montar uma parte da tabela em uma query e o restante das informações em outra query. ex, tenho que buscar os sites através de um GROUP BY em uma query para mostrar apenas o resultado de um site, e através de uma outra query, os dados que preciso, acontece que para a tabela ficar da forma que preciso, eu preciso que em um determinado momento ele feche o  com um , ou seja, se tiver 10 dados vindos, após este 10º dado, devo colocar um , fiz isso através de uma condição if no código, porém quando eu continuo o código, ele perde minha condição e o layout quebra inteiro, como eu quero que seja a tabela:

```
        SITE
     1  2  3  4
 A   V  V  V  V
 B   V  V  V  V
 C   V  V  V  V
 D   V  V  V  V
```

A estrutura da tabela seria dessa forma:

```
 <table>
    <tr>
        <th colspan='4'>SITE</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>5</td>
        <td>6</td>
        <td>7</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>A</td>
        <td>B</td>
        <td>C</td>
        <td>D</td>
        <td>V</td>
        <td>V</td>
        <td>V</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Meu código em PHP está da seguinte forma:

```
require_once("db.php");
$sql = $pdo->query("SELECT site FROM tabelactr GROUP BY site");
$resultsql1 = $sql->fetchAll();
$i=0;
foreach ($resultsql1 as $key => $value1) {
    $conteudo= "<table class='tg'><tr><th class='tg-0pky' colspan='4'>" . $value1['site'] . "</th></tr><tr><td class='tg-uys7'></td>";
    $sql2 = $pdo->query("SELECT pos,tamanhoCriativo,ctr FROM tabelactr WHERE site = '" . $value1['site'] . "' GROUP BY pos,tamanhoCriativo");
    $cont = $sql2->rowCount();
    foreach ($sql2 as $key2 => $value2) {
        $conteudo.= "<td class='tg-uys7'>" . $value2['tamanhoCriativo'] . "</td>";
        $i++;
        if ($i % $cont == 0) {
            echo "</tr>";
        }
        $conteudo.="<tr><td class='tg-0pky'>" . $value2['pos'] . "</td><td class='tg-xldj'>" . $value2['ctr'] . "</td></tr>"; //aqui está a linha onde está dando erro.
    }
    $conteudo.="</table>";
    print($conteudo);
}
```

O problema está ao continuar o código após o if onde escrevo o fechamento do tr, pois ele agrupa todos os valores que possuo, e não fica da forma como eu quero acima, alguém tem alguma idéia de como posso contornar este problema?

Obrigado!

Answer (score 0):

Mude para isso, alterei dentro do segundo foreach

```
require_once("db.php");
    $sql = $pdo->query("SELECT site FROM tabelactr GROUP BY site");
    $resultsql1 = $sql->fetchAll();
    $i=0;
    $conteudo = "<table class='tg'>";
    foreach ($resultsql1 as $key => $value1) {
        $conteudo .= "
                <tr>
                    <th class='tg-0pky' colspan='4'>" . $value1['site'] . "</th>
                </tr>";
        $sql2 = $pdo->query("SELECT pos,tamanhoCriativo,ctr FROM tabelactr WHERE site = '" . $value1['site'] . "' GROUP BY pos,tamanhoCriativo");
        $cont = $sql2->rowCount();
        foreach ($sql2 as $key2 => $value2) {
            $conteudo.= "<td class='tg-uys7'>" . $value2['tamanhoCriativo'] . "</td>";
            $i++;
            if ($i % $cont == 0) {
                echo "</tr>";
                echo "<tr>";
            }
            $conteudo.="<td class='tg-0pky'>" . $value2['pos'] . "</td><td class='tg-xldj'>" . $value2['ctr'] . "</td>"; //aqui está a linha onde está dando erro.

        }
        $conteudo.="</table>";
        print($conteudo);
    }
    $conteudo .= "</table>";
```